# Window 7 32 bit - Open blocked port

Tags: window, command

Can any body help me to reopen or close my blocked port.

I am using window 7 with 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you.

At the command prompt or "Run" , type: wf.msc

And then you see a full configuration of your firewall. other way is Click Start, click All Programs, click Administrative Tools, and then click Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.

And you see the rules of inbound and outbound, just search about your application or port that you want to enable.

Regards